# Asterisk GUI - Checking Write Permission for GUI Folder

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, asterisk, voip

I have installed Asterisk and Asterisk GUI on an Ubuntu Desktop 14.04. When I go to the GUI page and login it comes up and says "Checking write permission for gui folder" and stays on that screen.

http.conf file:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
bindaddr = 10.0.0.16
bindport = 8088
prefix = asterisk
;sessionlimit=100
enablestatic = yes
redirect = / /asterisk/static/config/index.htm
```

manager.conf file:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
webenabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 10.0.0.16

;#include "manager.d/*.conf"

[admin]
secret = admin
read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config
write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config,originate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those config files have no any relation.

1) check in asterisk.conf which user it use(usualy asterisk)

2) do

```
 chown asterisk /var/lib/asterisk/ /var/spool/asterisk -R
```

Comment: I ran this on my production server and it worked fine. What I did on my testing server for the mean while was 'chmod 777'

Answer (score 1):

`chmod 777` should only be required, when the user `asterisk` has not been added or when it's group membership is somehow messed up - otherwise a `chown` should be enough to open the `astdb.sqlite3` in read/write mode.

```
chown -R asterisk:asterisk /etc/asterisk/ /var/lib/asterisk /usr/share/asterisk
chmod 644 /etc/asterisk/*
```

[wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+GUI#AsteriskGUI-Troubleshooting)

Comment: inside /etc/asterisk/ there is a directory called manager.d that should have 755 permission instead of 644

Comment: @dAm2K just checked, my version only has a `manager.conf` there, while that directory might contain further configurations included in that file. `655` might work as well, while asterisk not wants to set permissions on the contained files, which commonly should be inherited from the parent.